# Por qué no se me deshabilita un botón en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hola amigos tengo esta etiqueta html

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-registro" class="button" value="Pagar">

 <script src="js/principal.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

```js
         var btn_registro=document.getElementById('btn-registro');
         

         /* Ahora desactivamos el botón de pagar o btn-registro para que solo se le pueda pulsar una vez se ha
         calculado el monto a pagar. */

         btn_registro.disabled="true";

        //  Añadimos el evento para el error de validacion de los cammpos de la persona
```

Pero a la hora de cargar el documento el boton me aparece activado. Por qué no se está desactivando puesto que el resto de código javascript si se está ejecutando? Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: El problema puede estar en este script: `<script src="js/principal.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>` o en tu código CSS. He hecho una prueba sin esa línea y el botón aparece desactivado. Aunque si quieres que de entrada el botón aparezca desactivado, lo puedes poner directamente en el HTML haciendo esto:  **`<input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-registro" class="button" value="Pagar" disabled>`**  Si no funciona así ,prueba sin el script ese que aparece al principio, y si aún así no funciona, es un problema en tu archivo css que activa el botón a través de la clase, o del id etc

Comment: Hola amigo. El problema es que si quito esa función no se veria absolutamente nada úesto que estoy desde php. Sino coloco esa funcion no se actualiza ni css ni js en el servidor de php

Comment: Bueno, pero si pones el HTML del botón y este código solamente en el header: `var btn_registro=document.getElementById('btn-registro'); btn_registro.disabled="true";` el botón sí se vería desactivado. Lo que te quiero decir es que si aparece activado es porque se activa desde otra parte, o porque hay error en el código Javascript previo. O prueba a poner ese código Javascript después de la desactivación del botón, o prueba a poner `disabled` en el HTML directamente y di qué resultados tienes.

Comment: Hola amigo. Encontré la solución: lo que debia hacer era lo siguiente:                         input[disabled].button { /**Dar efecto de deshabilitado al boton, codigo sacado de las preguntas, seccion 47, clase 384**/
    opacity: .5;
  }
y en js hacer esto:                                                                          if (btn_registro) {
            btn_registro.disabled="true";
 
         }

Comment: No entiendo mucho pero bueno... parece que estás usando algún framework o algo así, eso no me suena a Javascript puro ni a HTML  ¿?